# Creating commas around my product output

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, cartesian-product

I need to create a Cartesian product with user input. I have done that but the out put needs to have commas. I am just having a hard time getting that. So if you input 1,2 in ListA and 3,4 in ListB the outcome should be (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4).

Currently the output is as follows. ['1,3', '1,4', '2,3', '2,4']. I am sure I am missing something very simple, I just keep missing it.

Thank you for any insight.

```
ListA = input("Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:")
numbers = list(map(str, ListA.split(",")))

print(ListA)

ListB = input("Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:")
numbers = list(map(str, ListB.split(",")))

print(ListB)

import itertools

AxB = []

for i in itertools.product(ListA.split(","), ListB.split(",")):
    AxB.append(",".join(map(str, i)))

print(AxB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

list_a = map(int, input("Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:").split(","))
list_b = map(int, input("Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:").split(","))

axb = list(itertools.product(list_a, list_b))

print(axb)
```

seems to do what you want:

```
Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:1,2,3
Enter up to 10 numbers seperated by commas:4,5,6
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

(EDIT: misread the original question, reanswered...)